# Cambiar propiedad de clase al hacer hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia, tengo un elemento, que al hacer hover sobre el, se aplica lo siguiente:

```css
.classExample:hover div
{
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 950px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #D8EAD9;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 17px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    left : -450px;
}
```

Lo que no he logrado es que al ponerme sobre el, cambiar la propiedad top de esta misma clase, pueden guiarme, sobre como puedo hacerlo con jquery, cambiarlo por ejemplo a 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `.css` para cambiar la propiedad top o cualquier otra, de esta manera al hacer `mouseover` que es idéntico al hover de css podrás visualizar el cambio.

```js
$('.classExample').on('mouseover',function(){
  
  $(this).css({
    
    'top': '100px'
  
  });

});
```

```css
.classExample:hover 
{
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 950px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #D8EAD9;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 17px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    left : -450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classExample">DIV</div>
```